# Viewing PDF file in Windows Form application

Tags: c#, axacropdf

I am using axAcroPDF to view PDF files in in my win form application. Whenever I try to run the app I get an empty messagebox like in the image below.

Does anyone know why? To load the PDF file I added this code to a button

```
OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        dialog.Filter = "PDF files (*.PDF)|*.PDF|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        dialog.InitialDirectory = "C:";
        dialog.Title = "Select a PDF file";
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this.Controls.Add(this.axAcroPDF1);
            axAcroPDF1.src = dialog.FileName;
            filname1 = dialog.FileName;
            button2.Enabled = true;
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: can we see some code?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this answer can help you: I was doing the same work with Adobe Reader 9 and it gave me the same messagebox. Then I switch to Adobe Reader 10 and the message box disappears and my application works normally.

here is my code

```
        OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.Filter = "pdf files (*.pdf) |*.pdf;";
        dlg.ShowDialog();
        if (dlg.FileName != null)
        {
            axAcroPDF1.setShowToolbar(true);
            axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(dlg.FileName);
        }
```